# How can I get the value data out of an MSXML::IXMLDOMElement

Tags: c++, xml, msxml

I have an xml string

```
<grandparent>
   <parent>
       <child>dave</child>
       <child>laurie</child>
       <child>gabrielle</child>
   </parent>
</grandparrent>
```

What I want to get is the data raw xml that's inside the parent. 
I'm using MSXML

```
iXMLElm->get_xml(&bStr);
```

is returning

```
<parent>
   <child>dave</child>
   <child>laurie</child>
   <child>gabrielle</child>
</parent>
```

.

```
iXMLElm->get_text(&bStr);
```

returns 
davelauriegabrielle

**What function do I use if I want to get?**

```
<child>dave</child>
   <child>laurie</child>
   <child>gabrielle</child>
```

Is anyone aware of some good documentation on these functions? Everything I've seen is a linked nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the child nodes and build the string manually.

Comment: There are situations where this could be a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSXML, this should be a case of getting the child node of the grandparent node.

So, if `iXMLElm` is the grandparent and it has only one child node, you can just use...

```
 iXMLElm->get_firstChild(&iXMLChildElm)
```

...and then...

```
 iXMLChildElm->get_xml(&bStr)
```

...to get the three `child` elements.

If there are multiple items under `grandparent` you could use `selectSingleNode` instead to use XPath for selecting the node with the inner XML you want.

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757048(VS.85).aspx) is quite reasonable on the interfaces and calls available.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using IXMLDOMElement, then

```
HRESULT getAttribute(
    BSTR name,
    VARIANT *value);
```

is the method in which 'name' is attribute name and 'value' is output parameter which will contain value of the attribute in string format.